# Custom TouchDevice triggers Touch events at incorrect position

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I am using a custom TouchDevice (code below) to interact with UIElements. This TouchDevice causes TouchEnter and TouchLeave events to be triggered on UIElements to the bottom right of screen coodinates I pass to `Move(x,y)` rather than on the UIElement at these coordinates. How do I fix this?

This problem occurs on my Surface Pro 3 tablet (touchscreen, Windows 8.1), but not on my desktop (no touchscreen, Windows 7).

I first assumed the cause was an incorrect implementation of `GetTouchPoint(IInputElement relativeTo)`. However, this method is only called with relativeTo set to null.

```
public class CustomTouchDevice : TouchDevice
    {
        public Point Position { get; set; }

        private GazeTouchDevice(int id) : base(id)
        {
            SetActiveSource(PresentationSource.FromVisual(Application.Current.MainWindow));
        }

        public void Move(int x, int y)
        {
            if(!IsActive)
            {
                Activate();
                ReportDown();
            }
            Position = new Point(x, y);
            ReportMove();
        }

        public void Lost()
        {
            if(IsActive)
            {
                ReportUp();
                Deactivate();
            }
        }

        public override TouchPoint GetTouchPoint(IInputElement relativeTo)
        {
            Point point = Position;
            if(relativeTo != null)
            {
                point = this.ActiveSource.RootVisual.TransformToDescendant((Visual)relativeTo).Transform(Position);
            }
            Rect rect = new Rect(point, new Size(1, 1));
            return new TouchPoint(this, point, rect, TouchAction.Move);
        }

        public override TouchPointCollection GetIntermediateTouchPoints(IInputElement relativeTo)
        {
            return new TouchPointCollection();
        }
   }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing this first line of `GetTouchPoint` solved the problem:

```
Point point = ActiveSource.RootVisual.PointFromScreen(Position);
```

Apparently my application uses a coordinate system different from the screen coordinate system on my tablet. I suspect WPF transparently opts to not use the full resolution on the ultra-high definition tablet screen (2160x1440 px / 216 ppi).